# Problem with removing redundancy from a file

Tags: python, pandas, file, duplicates

I've got a DataSet with two columns, one with categorical value (`State2`), and another (`State`) that contains the same values only in binary.
I used `OneHotEncoding`.

```
import pandas as pd

mydataset = pd.read_csv('fieldprotobackup.binetflow')

mydataset.drop_duplicates(['Proto2','Proto'], keep='first')
mydataset.to_csv('fieldprotobackup.binetflow', columns=['Proto2','Proto'], index=False)
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1huWt.png)

I'd like to remove all redundancies from the file. While researching, I found the command `df.drop_duplicates`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: As the solution mentions below, you are not saving your drop_duplicates results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to add the `inplace=True` parameter, or you need to capture the returned dataframe:

```
mydataset.drop_duplicates(['Proto2','Proto'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

or

```
no_duplicates = mydataset.drop_duplicates(['Proto2','Proto'], keep='first')
```

Always a good idea to check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) when something isn't working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now, but when i run the program it simply erases the zeroes that are left to the 1.
https://imgur.com/a/OU07DzX

Comment: You should post another question, however your issues looks like you are treating the binary numbers as integers which is why leading zeros are truncated. In the meantime, accept the answer that answered this question specifically

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm new to the forum.